# Deciphering chinese address

Tags: names, place-names

I have to send a package to a chinese address. This is the address the seller gave me:

> zhuwei *12345678901*
>
> China zhe jiang sheng jin hua shi yi wu shi *7*th Floor, Building *3*,
> Kaichuang Park, No.*123*, *Foo* Road, *Bar* Street
>
> CN *123456* jin hua shi zhe jiang sheng

(Note that I changed the parts in *italic* in order to anonymize the address a bit. I always kept the number of digits the same as in the original address.)

I cannot just write free text onto the parcel, I have to follow the format:

[image]

Can anyone help me put the correct bits of that adress into the form? More concretely:

- What is the first and last name?
- I assume postal code is *123456*?
- What is the town/city?
- There is Road and Street in the address, so what do I write into the street textbox? And what about the Kaichuang Park, shouldn't that be part of that entry too?
- What is the house number? Building *3*?
- What is the province?
- What is all the rest of that address?

Answer (score 1):

First name: Wei 12345678901 (What is this number for?)

Last Name: Zhu

Postal Code: 123456

Town/City: jinhua shi, yiwu shi (Why lists two cities?)

Street: No.123 Foo Road, Bar Street

House Number: 7th Floor, Building 3, Kaichuang Park

Province: Zhe jiang sheng

Comment: Pretty sure 12345678901 is the phone number.

Comment: Sounds right. :)

Comment: Also re why they listed two cities: this is a special administrative oddity, yiwu (义乌）is technically a direct-administered county-level city under Zhejiang province, but it's under the jurisdiction of jinhua (金华), a prefecture-level city.

Comment: Yes, a weird political system/arrandement, as economically 金华 has long been exceeded by 义乌 :) https://www.zhihu.com/question/264785919